# Clear entire, transformed HTML5 Canvas while preserving context transform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to zoom and pan an HTML5 Canvas by transforming the context using `translate()` and `scale()`, clearing the canvas, and then redrawing. Note that I am explicitly *not* calling `save()` and `restore()` around my transformations.

If I perform the standard `ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)` then the entire visible canvas will not be cleared; downscaling or panning may cause this initial rectangle to not exactly cover the drawing area.

If I perform the Webkit-friendly clearing method...

```
var w=canvas.width;
canvas.width = 0;
canvas.width = w;
```

...then the cumulative transformation of the context is reset.

How can I best clear the entire canvas context without losing my transformation?

Comment: The sucker-ish way would be to store you scales and translates and then calculate the bounding rectangle yourself, but one would hope that there is a better way.

Comment: @JakubHampl That's actually what I'm doing, since I'm already keeping track of the transform and have added method to transform from screen space to canvas space, but this seemed like a good opportunity to point out the problems with these two clearing methods and see if there's something cleaner.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Keeping track of all the transformation information like you are presumably doing is what several others so far have done (like cake.js and my own library, for two). I think doing this will pretty much be an inevitability for any large canvas library.

Ilmari of cake.js even complained to mozilla:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=408804

You could instead call save/restore around your clear method:

```
// I have lots of transforms right now
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
// Will always clear the right space
ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.restore();
// Still have my old transforms
```

Won't that satisfy your case?

Comment: How silly of me; I was trying to think how to get the identity matrix, but was thinking of needing the current transform to calculate the inverse and then multiply by that. Yes, this should do nicely.

Comment: Glad I could help. I wanted to also say thanks for all your contributions to the canvas topic on S.O.

Answer (score 5):

For those who care to track their full context transforms, here's my code for doing so in an on-demand, per-context basis. This is prefaced with the usage that shows how to clear the full rectangle based on the transformed coordinates. You can see [the code in use](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html) on my website.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  trackTransforms(ctx);
  function redraw(){
    var p1 = ctx.transformedPoint(0,0);
    var p2 = ctx.transformedPoint(canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.clearRect(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x-p1.x,p2.y-p1.y);
    // ... 
  }
}


// Adds ctx.getTransform(), returning an SVGMatrix
// Adds ctx.transformedPoint(x,y), returning an SVGPoint
function trackTransforms(ctx){
  var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'svg');
  var xform = svg.createSVGMatrix();
  ctx.getTransform = function(){ return xform; };

  var savedTransforms = [];
  var save = ctx.save;
  ctx.save = function(){
    savedTransforms.push(xform.translate(0,0));
    return save.call(ctx);
  };
  var restore = ctx.restore;
  ctx.restore = function(){
    xform = savedTransforms.pop();
    return restore.call(ctx);
  };

  var scale = ctx.scale;
  ctx.scale = function(sx,sy){
    xform = xform.scaleNonUniform(sx,sy);
    return scale.call(ctx,sx,sy);
  };
  var rotate = ctx.rotate;
  ctx.rotate = function(radians){
    xform = xform.rotate(radians*180/Math.PI);
    return rotate.call(ctx,radians);
  };
  var translate = ctx.translate;
  ctx.translate = function(dx,dy){
    xform = xform.translate(dx,dy);
    return translate.call(ctx,dx,dy);
  };
  var transform = ctx.transform;
  ctx.transform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
    var m2 = svg.createSVGMatrix();
    m2.a=a; m2.b=b; m2.c=c; m2.d=d; m2.e=e; m2.f=f;
    xform = xform.multiply(m2);
    return transform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
  };
  var setTransform = ctx.setTransform;
  ctx.setTransform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
    xform.a = a;
    xform.b = b;
    xform.c = c;
    xform.d = d;
    xform.e = e;
    xform.f = f;
    return setTransform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
  };
  var pt  = svg.createSVGPoint();
  ctx.transformedPoint = function(x,y){
    pt.x=x; pt.y=y;
    return pt.matrixTransform(xform.inverse());
  }
}
```

Comment: This example ist great and helped me alot, but there is still one problem I can not get my head around: How would you clear the canvas in redraw(), if your image is rotated at serveral points of the image?

Comment: @Kevkong Exactly like the accepted answer shows: save the context transform, reset the transform to the identity matrix, clear the 0,0,width,height, and restore the transform.

Comment: Yea you are right, I just misspelled something so "restore" wouldnt work as intended and transformedPoint returned the wrong point after a restore. thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, but for those who need, the API has quite evolved here and it's now trivial to do so.

First, to clear the canvas don't use the `canvas.width += 0` trick. This might have been decent in the old days, but now that the canvas buffer lives in the GPU doing so comes with a relatively noticeable performance hit. There is a [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/reset) method, which just like the canvas size trick will reset all the context's state, but from my early tests it didn't use to be terribly more performant, so the best if all you want is to clear the pixel buffer is probably to reset the current transformation matrix (CTM) using the [`ctx.resetTransform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/resetTransform) method and use [`clearRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) to clear the pixels buffer.

Then to the actual question, there is a [`getTransform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getTransform) method, that will return the CTM as a [`DOMMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) object.

So one could call that method before resetting the CTM (be it through `resetTransform()`, `canvas.width += 0`, or `reset()`), and then pass the saved `DOMMatrix()` object to [`setTransform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform), which does accept such object as input (or any JS object that matches the signature of such an object).

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let direction = 1;
function anim() {
  const matrix = ctx.getTransform();
  ctx.resetTransform();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10); // fixed point
  ctx.setTransform(matrix);
  // We move our rect by changing the CTM
  ctx.translate(direction, 0);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 50, 50, 50);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
anim();

// Change direction every 2s
setInterval(() => direction *= -1, 2000);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But, since `setTransform()` can accept a `DOMMatrix`, you could actually keep such an object alive in your code and use that directly instead of requesting every frame for the current one:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const matrix = new DOMMatrix();
let direction = 1;
function anim() {
  matrix.translateSelf(direction, 0);
  ctx.resetTransform();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10); // fixed point
  ctx.setTransform(matrix);
  ctx.fillRect(10, 50, 50, 50);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
anim();

// Change direction every 2s
setInterval(() => direction *= -1, 2000);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```